# Understanding BFS tree traversal by levels on the sample

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I'm learning how to traverse a tree by levels. The method I do should take the level of tree number and print back a nodes at the current level.
I watched [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-binary-search-tree-data-structure-and-algorithm-tutorials/) - "Print nodes at given Level", but still can't figure out how is recursion working in this concrete sample.
So please, help me to understand.

```
// Java program for Inserting a node
class GFG1 {

    static class node {
        int key;
        node left, right;
    }

    static node newNode(int item)
    {
        node temp = new node();
        temp.key = item;
        temp.left = temp.right = null;
        return temp;
    }

    // Function to insert a new node
    static node insert(node node, int key)
    {
        // If the tree is empty, return a new node
        if (node == null)
            return newNode(key);

        // Otherwise, recur down the tree
        if (key < node.key) {
            node.left = insert(node.left, key);
        }
        else if (key > node.key) {
            node.right = insert(node.right, key);
        }
        return node;
    }

    static void printGivenLevel(node root, int level)
    {
        if (root == null)
            return;
        if (level == 1) {
            System.out.print(" " + root.key);
        }
        else if (level > 1) {
            printGivenLevel(root.left, level - 1);
            printGivenLevel(root.right, level - 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        node root = null;
        root = insert(root, 50);insert(root, 30);insert(root, 20);insert(root, 40);insert(root, 70);insert(root, 60);insert(root, 80);
        printGivenLevel(root,2);

    }
}
```

The method of traversal by levels is `printGivenLevel`:
So why it requires to write `level-1` in  `printGivenLevel(root.left, level - 1)`  and not works with 'level +1', for example?
How do we come to the base condition, for example on the 3-th or 2-nd tier?

The tree looks like

```
   50
  30 70
20 40 60 80
```

Comment: `level` means how  many levels we are away from the one we want to print. `if (level == 1)` means we are in the level we want to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`level` is an ambiguous term here, in the `printGivenLevel` it starts from the top "level", which is technically `level 1`, and we recurse down until we reach our desired "level".

```
    Actual level       "level" inside printGivenLevel(root, level)    
        1          50              3
        2        30   70           2
        3      20 40 60 80         1
```

Let's see how `printGivenLevel(root, 2)` executes, renaming `printGivenLevel` as `print`:

```
 1. print(root, 2) -> print(root.left(30), 1) and print(root.right(70), 1)
 2. print(root(30), 1) -> we are at "level 1", print the value 30.
 3. print(root(70), 1) -> we are at "level 1", print the value 70.
```

The base condition always reaches when "level" becomes equal to 1, we start **counting down** from the top level, and when we reach our desired level, the "level" count becomes 1 and we print the value of the node.

> So why it requires to write level-1 in  printGivenLevel(root.left, level - 1) and not works with 'level +1', for example? How do we come to the base condition, for example on the 3-th or 2-nd tier?

If `level` is always increased, it'll keep on increasing and won't reach level 1, no value would be printed and it'd result in stackoverflow.